# IHttpClientFactory cache not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I might misunderstand the workings of the `IHttpClientFactory`, basically what I want to do is in my `asp.net core` project is create a cached client at runtime in for example my controller.

Example:

```
Program.cs
...
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
...
```

Then in my controller (just the default asp.net core project from Microsoft as example)

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var test = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("test");
            test.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com/");

            var test2 = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("test");
        }
    }
```

What I expected is at `test2` my client would have set the default base address to `https://google.com`, this is unfortunately not the case however. All custom headers and/or
base-addresses are un-set.

I was under the impression that the `HttpClientFactory` would store this in-memory. Am I misunderstanding the workings of the `HttpClientFactory` or am I missing something else? Note: I cannot define this in program.cs, it has to be done like above (if possible at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The life cycle management

- the [factories](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23)  are registered as *Singleton*

  - like `IHttpClientFactory`, `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory`
- the [named clients](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L47) as *Transient*
- and the [typed clients](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L274) as *Transient* as well

An `HttpClient`'s life cycle is short, but the underlying `HttpClientMessageHandler`s are [pooled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
([related source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e55c908229e36f99a52745d4ee85316a0e8bb6a2/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L44))

> Manages the pooling and lifetime of underlying HttpClientMessageHandler instances. Automatic management avoids common DNS (Domain Name System) problems that occur when manually managing HttpClient lifetimes

#### `CreateClient` method call

This [method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4677b0dc8b411a8adc46cdf1f498f56527177105/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L98) is creating a lightweight `HttpClient` instance. It calls the [`CreateHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4677b0dc8b411a8adc46cdf1f498f56527177105/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L114) method which fetches the underlying pooled `HttpMessageHandler`.

So, the observed behaviour is the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is When you call `_httpClientFactory.CreateClient("test")` twice in your code, you are actually creating two separate instances of **HttpClient** with the same name ("test"), but they are not the same object in memory. The HttpClient instances created by the factory are not cached or reused automatically based on their configuration or name.

If you want to reuse an HttpClient instance with a specific configuration, you can use the IHttpClientFactory to create and configure the HttpClient instance once, and then store it in a cache for reuse.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
  private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
  private readonly MemoryCache _cache;

  public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHttpClientFactory 
  httpClientFactory, MemoryCache cache)
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    _cache = cache;
  }

  public void OnGet()
  {
    const string clientName = "test";
    var test = _cache.GetOrCreate(clientName, entry =>
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(clientName);
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com/");
        return httpClient;
    });

    var test2 = _cache.GetOrCreate(clientName, entry => test);

    // Use test and test2 as needed
  }
}
```

`Caution:` If the base address or other configuration properties of the HttpClient instance change frequently, caching may not be appropriate. Additionally, caching can cause issues with resource management if too many HttpClient instances are created and cached.